# About CountIF Function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, counting, countif

I'm new to Excel. I have an excel table and I want to make a formula to avoid manual process. Because sometimes it might be so sophisticated.

Here is the table I want to write formula. My main aim is to find to specific number which letter is assigned.

| Letter | Number | Letter | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 132 | C | 134 |
| A | 132 | C | 134 |
| B | 132 | D | 135 |
| B | 132 | E | 132 |
| A | 132 | D | 135 |
| C | 134 | A | 132 |
| C | 134 |  |  |

According to table, the expected result should be like below.

| 132 | 3 | Because, it is used for A, B, and E letters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 134 | 1 | Because, it is used for only C letter |
| 135 | 2 |  |

How to obtain a result like above?

Comment: You state you want the result based on the "C, D, G and H columns", and are surprised that columns A and E are not included. You did not include them.

Comment: How to write condition into countif formula by including A and E columns or I should think anything else.

Comment: So you want a count per column A and E value and per value in columns C, D, G and H. Can you add your sample data via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) - then it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: I converted the picture into table by using Markdown Table Generator. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you got Excel 365 sounds like you want to count unique values of combined Letter & Number fields.

Comment: Is your first table supposed to be only 2 columns?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that for 135 it should be 1 and not 2 since D is repeated two times.

```
=LET(z,VSTACK(A2:B8,C2:D7),x,UNIQUE(TAKE(z,,-1)),HSTACK(x,MAP(x,LAMBDA(a,SUM(N(TAKE(UNIQUE(z),,-1)=a))))))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted, then one could use one of the following to arrive at the desired output.* All the formulas posted below are one single input with dynamic array formula:

• Using `GROUPBY()` --> Applicable to `MS365` Beta Version.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:D8,
     _Flip, TAKE(UNIQUE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(_Data,1),2)),,-1),
     GROUPBY(_Flip,_Flip,COUNT,,0))
```

---

Or, Using `MMULT()`

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:D8,
     _Flip, TAKE(UNIQUE(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(_Data,1),2)),,-1),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(_Flip,MMULT(N(_Flip=TOROW(_Flip)),_Flip^0))))
```

---

Comment: Nice +1. Still didn't have the chance to try those new functions. Can't wait to

Comment: I got the error when I wrote this formula in the blank cell. The error is the "The first argument of Let function must be a valid name". It might be an easy solution for this error. But, I didn't understand how to apply the excel sheet.

Comment: @bcdyzi do you have any named ranges as `_Data`? Also `GROUPBY()` is applicable to `MS365` Beta Version users, as informed in the first line, you could try the one in the second method

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your data is in two ranges `"Letters"` and `"Numbers"` (if you actually have several columns, they can be combined using `VSTACK()` but we will skip this).

If each number is assigned to one and only one letter, and if the desired result is counting how many times each number appears -

Then what you need is very straightforward:

Left column (cell А1): `=UNIQUE(Numbers)`

Right column (cell B1): `=COUNTIF(Numbers,А1#)`

You really do not need `Letters` as all as long as every number is unique for every letter.

Let me know if you have a different algorithm in mind.